# How to paginate with an query var appended to permalink?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, url-rewriting

I have a function that applies a query_var to all links in a page if the query_var exists for the current page.

So if I change

https://liquidchurch.com/messages/

to

https://liquidchurch.com/messages/messages-app-view/

then all the links on the page are updated to look something like this:

https://liquidchurch.com/sermon-series/divine-direction/message-app-view/

The problem is with the pagination at the bottom of the page. If you look at the /messages page while messages-app-view is appended you'll see that the permalink to the next page looks like:

https://liquidchurch.com/messages/messages-app-view/page/2/

Problem is that this will return a 404. Ideally I'd like for the URL to be:

https://liquidchurch.com/messages/page/2/messages-app-view/

Alternatively, I suppose a regex would work that checks if /page/x/ is listed after messages-app-view.

Thoughts on how I should accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Is "messages-app-view" necessary in the url of your requests?  If you're using it to toggle the display of a component or the layout/view mode of the pages, you may want to consider using HTML localStorage (similar to a cookie).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the regex. In my case that looks like:

```
 add_rewrite_rule('^messages/messages-app-view/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 
'index.php?pagename=messages&messages-app-view&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
```